# How to refer to individual columns of a record returned by a function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a function that returns `setof record` type.

```
CREATE TYPE CIR_TYPE AS
(
    ID integer,
    path text,
    cycle boolean
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION circular_ref() RETURNS setof CIR_TYPE AS $body$

DECLARE
    r CIR_TYPE;

BEGIN
    For r in WITH RECURSIVE graph(ID, path, cycle) AS (
                SELECT id AS id
                     , ARRAY[parentid, id] AS path
                     , (parentid = id) AS cycle    
                FROM  mytable

                UNION ALL

                SELECT d.id, d.parentid ||path, d.parentid = ANY(path)
                FROM   graph g
                JOIN   mytable d ON d.id = g.path[1]
                WHERE  NOT g.cycle
             )
             SELECT DISTINCT *
             FROM   graph
    Loop

        If r.cycle= TRUE then
        Return NEXT r;
        End if;

    End loop;

END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute the above function I get an output like below:

```
circular_ref
----------------------------
(0,"{1,0,1}",t)
(1,"{0,1,0}",t)
```

Here `0` and `1` are `ID`, `{0,1,0}` and `{0,1,0}` are `path` and `t` indicates cycle.

I want to print the output like

```
ID     |    Path
----       ------
0      |   1,0,1
1      |   0,1,0
```

Please suggest how to get the expected result.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't really need a loop or PL/pgSQL here. A simple SQL query (or function) will do just fine

Comment: Probably you will be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370271/4632019)

Answer (score 8):

The problem, I guess, hits everyone starting with PostgreSQL.  Fortunately, the solution is rather easy: simply call

```
SELECT * FROM circular_ref();
```

instead of

```
SELECT circular_ref();
```

This way it won't be a single record you get but a proper row.  This way, you can even do

```
SELECT id, path FROM circular_ref();
```

to get the columns you want.

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING** Disadvantage of next method is that the call to `circular_ref` is made for each field returned by `circular_ref`

---

You can expand record:

```
select (circular_ref()).*;
```

Or refer to individual column:

```
select (circular_ref()).ID, (circular_ref()).path  -- Here circular_ref will be called twice
```

Just wrap your record into `()` and then refer to its field via `.` as usual.

Any table returns set of records and you refer to its fields as `table.field`:

```
select t.field1, t.field2 from table t;
```

**UPD**
Nice [article](https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/201-returns-table.html) but, probably, already outdated

Comment: No. `select * from circular_ref()` is the correct way to use that (as shown in deszo's answer)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: what is disadvantages of method I have shown?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) "*Table functions [...] They are used like a table, view, or subquery in the FROM clause of a query*". Would you ever write `select (some_table).*` - probably not, so why do it with a function that is essentially the same as a table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: probably because of a habit, bad habit. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: would it be OK to use `().*` syntax for not table functions? For example: `function t2 ( out id int, out name text )`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this question for almost a day. Both answers are useful but I had problem with first answer @dezso. My function parameters are coming from a table so I cannot move function down to FROM, it has to be a select-list. Here is the example:

```
select heptathlon_transpose(array_agg(array[hurdles, highjump, shot, run200m, longjump, javelin, run800m]))
from heptathlon
```

Only option I had to use @Eugen Konkov's answer. This is how the query looks:

```
select (heptathlon_transpose(array_agg(array[hurdles, highjump, shot, run200m, longjump, javelin, run800m]))).* 
from heptathlon
```

And it works like a charm.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a good way to do that. You should put the set returning function into the from clause using a lateral join: `select ht.*
from heptathlon
  cross join heptathlon_transpose(hurdles, highjump, shot, run200m, longjump, javelin, run800m]) as ht `